# Join two rows together if they share the same value?

Tags: database, t-sql

I've shifted through views and other points and I've gotten to here.  Take example below

```
 Name     | Quantity | Billed |
          |          |        |
 PC Tablet|   0      |  100   |
 PC Tablet|   100    | -2345  |
 Monitor  |   9873   | 0      |
 Keyboard |   200    | -300   |
```

So basically the select I would do off this view. I would want it to Bring in the data BUT it be ordered by the Name first so its in nice alphabetical order and also for a few reasons some of the records appear more then once (I think the most is 4 times). If you add the up the rows with duplicates the true 'quantity' and 'billed' would be correct.

NOTE: The actual query  is very long but I broke it down for a simple example to explain the problem. The idea is the same but there is A LOT MORE columns that needs to be added together... So I'm looking for a query that would bring them together if it contains the same name. I've tried a bunch of different queries with no success either it rolls ALL the rows into one. or it won't work and I get a bunch of null errors/ name column is invalid in the select list/group by because it's not an aggregate function..

Is this even possible?

Comment: What outcome you would like to have based on data you have provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT A.Name, A.TotalQty, B.TotalBilled
FROM (
 SELECT Name, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQty
 FROM YourTableHere
 GROUP BY Name
 ) A
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT Name, SUM(Billed) as TotalBilled
 FROM YourTableHere
 GROUP BY Name
) B
ON A.Name = B.Name
```

Comment: Thank you this template for the Query worked! You came up with that pretty quickly O_O

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. You could accept my answer as the soluttion to your problem by clicking on the check mark on the left side. GOD bless and happy coding!